# Alternatives for wizard and tab based UI

Tags: html, user-interface, tabs, wizard, user-experience

I'm working with modifying the existing user information form to more user friendly. For that I need more inputs on design level.

Now the input form is designed as wizard. But it is not recommended, since now it has almost 6 steps wizard. (Going 6 pages with next previous button).
Another approach would be going for tab based UI.
But it may be complex when we go to development.

Are there any other best alternatives?

Comment: Please explain your problem a little better and provide some view or codes for what you have tried so far. Right now it's a little hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't have any code to share. But simply I want to change the UI design which is currently implemented as a wizard. (Reason is client hates wizard UI). I'm searching for an alternate.

Comment: first you must show old form wizard to give us some additional information. I think One way is using ajax and submit step by step each part of current form to make more reliable and more user friendly.

Comment: This question seems like it would be better suited to ux.stackexchange, since it's about design instead of code.